# Is there a single word that means above and in front?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word that means above and in front?

Like "The cabinet is above and in front of my head."

Comment: I don’t believe there is a single word in common use. However, there is a medical term: [*anterosuperior*](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/anterosuperior).

Comment: Pilots would use the phrase "12-O'Clock high".

Comment: _Jutting over_ and _looming over_ are about as close as we can get. These give the sense of being ever so slightly threatened by the cabinet's position, which conveys the idea they're in front, too. There are also _overlooking_, _overhanging_, which don't really give a sense of being in front. None of these are clear, though.

Answer (score 1):

I posed the question to a Radiographer (my wife) and she immediately answered 'antero-superior'. Medical language is extremely accurate, and needs to be, and for that reason I believe it is the best single word answer (normally hyphenated). However it's not commonly understood. Some Military language is also extremely accurate, as in Kipling's poem "Gunga Din", where the regimental water-carrier was very accurately described as "squatting 50 paces right flank rear". The problem is that we have no concise language that is universal and accurate in describing a specific relative position in space. For that reason I fear we will nearly always use a cumbersome phrase. 
An extremely good question that goes "above & beyond".

Answer (score 0):

[Jut](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/jut) seems to fit the criterium of being in front of, but also to be overhanging.
1. to extend beyond the main body or line; project; protrude: a strip of land jutting out into the bay.
2. something that juts out; a projecting or protruding point.

Comment: Nope, the over-hanging quality makes it incorrect, 'cause I didn't ask for overhanging.